# SQL Having aggregate function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, min, having

I have table with students and evaluations. It is necessary to return the number of repetitions all ratings but without MIN and MAX number of repetitions grade.

When I'am runnig this query:

```
SELECT 
     [Grade],
     COUNT([Grade]) AS [Number of repetitions]
     FROM [Test].[dbo].[Evaluation]
     GROUP BY Grade
```

I have this result and it is ok, but how to show this query withuout MIN and MAX Number of repetitions.(In that case 6 - 120 and 10 - 4)

```
Grade    Number of repetitions
 6              120
 7              35
 8              93
 9              25
10              4
```

I tried wtih HAVING on this way, but it does not work. This is message in SQL: "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery"

```
SELECT 
     [Grade],
     COUNT([Grade]) AS [Number of repetitions]
     FROM [Test].[dbo].[Evaluation]
     GROUP BY Grade 
     HAVING COUNT([Grade) > (SELECT MIN(COUNT([Grade])) FROM [Test][dbo].[Evaluation] GROUP BY Grade) 
     AND 
     HAVING COUNT([Grade) < (SELECT MAX(COUNT([Grade])) FROM [Test][dbo].[Evaluation] GROUP BY Grade)
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 1):

You cannot nest aggregation functions like that.  There are many approaches you could use for solving this.  In your case, you can get the extreme values using `TOP` and `ORDER BY`:

```
 HAVING COUNT([Grade) > (SELECT TOP 1 COUNT([Grade]) FROM [Test].[dbo].[Evaluation] GROUP BY Grade ORDER BY COUNT([Grade]) ASC ) AND
        COUNT([Grade) < (SELECT TOP 1 COUNT([Grade]) FROM [Test].[dbo].[Evaluation] GROUP BY Grade ORDER BY COUNT([Grade]) DESC)
```

In addition, the `HAVING` keyword is used only once.

Answer (score 1):

```
select TT.* 
FROM ( SELECT [Grade] 
            , COUNT([Grade]) AS [Number of repetitions]
            , ROW_NUMBER OVER (ORDER BY COUNT([Grade]) desc) rnD 
            , ROW_NUMBER OVER (ORDER BY COUNT([Grade]) asc)  rnA
         FROM [Test].[dbo].[Evaluation]
        GROUP BY Grade 
     ) TT
WHERE  TT.rnD <> 1 AND TT.rnA <> 1
```

Comment: You should give one the check mark answer.  I don't care if you give the answer to Gordon.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH Fact As
(
SELECT 
     [Grade],
     COUNT([Grade]) AS [Number of repetitions]
     FROM [Test].[dbo].[Evaluation]
     GROUP BY Grade
)

SELECT Grade, [Number of repetitions] FROM Fact 
WHERE 
[Number of repetitions] NOT IN
(
(SELECT MAX([Number of repetitions]) FROM Fact), 
(SELECT MIN([Number of repetitions]) FROM Fact)
)
```

Here we are using the concept of Common Table Expression which is similar to sub query.

Comment: Cool! Glad that it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem on this way, but is CTE is good example. Thanks everyone.

```
SELECT 
      [Grade],
      COUNT([Grade]) AS [Number of repetitions]
      FROM [Test].[dbo].[Evaluation]
      GROUP BY Grade 
      HAVING COUNT([Grade) > (SELECT MIN(COUNT([Grade])) FROM [Test][dbo].[Evaluation] GROUP BY Grade) 
 AND 
      HAVING COUNT([Grade) < (SELECT MAX(COUNT([Grade])) FROM [Test][dbo].[Evaluation] GROUP BY Grade)
```